# Working on $emit, how to add function to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little problem with the logic of my app here. I am working with an $emit but that $emit is not working as I want

I have 2 different controllers

**betSlipCtrl.js**

here I have this function

```
$scope.removeSlip = function(slip) {

  //HERE THE EMIT
  $rootScope.$emit('betSlip:removeLines');

  BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip).then(function() {


  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

and then **linesCtrl.js**

```
$scope.addLineToBetSlip = function(line, row, type) {

  //HERE THE EMIT
  $rootScope.$on('betSlip:removeLines', function() {
    BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);
  });

  var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
    totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
    moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline');
  if (spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected) {
    BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);
  }else {
    BetSlipFactory.add(line, row, type);
  }
};
```

[I recorded a video for you to understand what I am doing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWHn1zpZHq8&feature=youtu.be)

as you might see in the video: in the 1st attempt I did, you select one line and you are able to remove it with no issue, but in the 2nd and 3rd attempt, I selected 4 lines, and once you try to remove one, the 4 lines has been removed. That's what I want to avoid.

The object `slip` is the one I need to remove, line by line and not the whole lines.

**UPDATE**

see the service here

```
  remove: function(line, row, type) {
    var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
      totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
      moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
      lineValue;
    if (spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected) {
      switch (type) {
        case 'spread':
          lineValue = row.spread.line;
          break;
        case 'total':
          lineValue = row.total.line;
          break;
        case 'moneyline':
          lineValue = row.moneyLineId;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      if (spreadSelected) {
        row.spreadSelected = false;
      }
      if (totalSelected) {
        row.totalSelected = false;
      }
      if (moneyLineSelected) {
        row.moneyLineSelected = false;
      }
    }
    return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/removeSelection', {
      game: row.game,
      pair: row.pair,
      line: lineValue
    });
  },
  add: function(line, row, type) {

    var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
      totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
      moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline'),
      lineValue;

    if (!(spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected)) {
      switch (type) {
        case 'spread':
          lineValue = row.spread.line;
          break;
        case 'total':
          lineValue = row.total.line;
          break;
        case 'moneyline':
          lineValue = row.moneyLineId;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      switch (type) {
        case 'spread':
          row.spreadSelected = true;
          break;
        case 'total':
          row.totalSelected = true;
          break;
        case 'moneyline':
          row.moneyLineSelected = true;
          break;
      }
    }
    return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/addSelection', {
      game: row.game,
      pair: row.pair,
      line: lineValue
    });
  },
  removeSlip: function(slip) {
    return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/removeSelection', {
      game: slip.game,
      pair: slip.pair,
      line: slip.line
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you every time you add a new line, you register a handler for the generic event that occurs whenever you remove *any* line, not just the line you just added.

However, you can add arguments when `$broadcast`/`$emit`ing events, [as per the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit). So I suggest you try something like the following:

**betSlipCtrl.js**

```
$scope.removeSlip = function(slip) {

  //HERE THE EMIT
  $rootScope.$emit('betSlip:removeLines', slip);

  BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip).then(function() {


  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

and then **linesCtrl.js**

```
$scope.addLineToBetSlip = function(line, row, type) {

  //HERE THE EMIT
  // The first argument to $on() is always the event object,
  // so we need to define 2 params to get at the slip object passed in.
  $rootScope.$on('betSlip:removeLines', function(event, slip) {
    BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip);
  });

  var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
    totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
    moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline');
  if (spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected) {
    BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);
  }else {
    BetSlipFactory.add(line, row, type);
  }
};
```

I'm not sure I got the exact removal code right, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. You might need to make sure you are actually removing lines from the right slip first or something.

One final point: the difference between `$emit` and `$broadcast` is that `$emit` starts at the scope you call it on and goes *up* the scope tree from there, whereas `$broadcast` starts at the scope you call it on and goes *down* the scope tree. Typically, if you are using `$rootScope`, you want to use `$broadcast` so you start at the top and allow all other scopes in the entire application to listen to that event. With the way you have done it, only the `$rootScope` can have listeners on it for that event, since there is nothing higher than it. That might be deliberate, but it seems like a mistake from here, so at least put a comment explaining why you did it that way if it is deliberate.

Comment: Because I don't have access to your full code base, and I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. You didn't include enough details that I could see for me to write the correct code there. You should change that line to whatever makes sense.

Comment: stay here with me, I'll be updating my stuff as fast as I can

Comment: check the update, Greg. Let me know if you need something else

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer What is the function that removes a single line from the `slip`? It seems like you have posted the code that removes a whole slip, rather than the one that removes a single line (the one that gets called when you click the single `x` on the right hand side in the video). Is that correct?

Comment: look at this functions: ```removeSlip()``` and ```remove()``` I have a function named ```removeAll()``` to remove all slips. ```removeAll:function() { return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betslip/clear'{});},``` all those are in the service.

Comment: in the controller I have:```$scope.removeSlip()``` which is the function to remove one by one

Comment: so, that's is all I have to remove slips, in the service: ```remove()``` and ```removeSlip(slip)``` in the controller: ```$scope.removeSlip(slip)``` and that functions must be reflected in the linesCtrl here ```$scope.addLineToBetSlip(line, row, type)``` that's why I am doing the broadcast

Comment: I don't know enough about your data model to be able to do all your work for you. I should have given you the tool you need (passing arguments with events) to get unstuck and fix the problem yourself from here. Embrace the struggle, [it leads to mental growth](https://www.khanacademy.org/about/blog/post/95208400815/the-learning-myth-why-ill-never-tell-my-son-hes). :-)